# Smarty : use regex and get output (Prestashop)

Tags: php, regex, smarty, prestashop

I try to get only the **first src img path from HTML** variable with Smarty (I am using it within Prestashop).

I do have this variable :

```
{$cmspages.content}
```

And need to extract from it the **first image source**, like :

```
I am a butterfly <img src="http://www.localhost.com" /> you know ?
```

And I need to have :

```
http://www.localhost.com
```

I did try some **regex** command or **strstr** but nothing come's up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Smarty you can use a variable outside of template syntax like this:

```
$this->get_template_vars('cmspages').content
```

Getting first img's src:

```
preg_match("~<img.+?src=\"([^"]+)\"~", $this->get_template_vars('cmspages').content, $match);
```

scr attribute's value is stored in `$match[1]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Anyway I am not able to add PHP code within a page, all methods I tested did not work and were btw deprecated in Prestashop... Thanks again